# What do you believe to be the best CSS Grid system and why?

Tags: css, comparison, grid-layout

I've been using Nicole Sullivan's "Object Oriented" CSS grid for a while now (hate the term, though) and have found it to be quite good.  However, as I get more experience with grids, I'm noticing a lot of other frameworks out there; in particular the [960 Grid System](http://960.gs/) and the [Yahoo! UI Library](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/grids/).

I'm looking for other peoples' experiences with these alternatives (or others) so I can make a more well-founded decision on whether to change or not.

Comment: While the grid systems are great for computer monitors, I really don't like how the wide layouts look on Blackberries and iPhones. Especially the 960 wide ones. Fluid layouts work so much better on the phones (mostly).

Comment: Fair point.  Especially since so much emphasis is being shifted to mobile devices.  Does anyone know how Blueprint or their preferred grid system translates to a mobile device?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think [Blueprint](http://blueprintcss.org/) is the best.

Also review comments posted at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/589184/help-me-choose-a-css-framework-960-vs-blueprint-vs

I found the noupe site has great comparisons for CSS frameworks and helped me choose: http://www.noupe.com/css/5-popular-css-frameworks-tutorials-tools-for-getting-started.html

If you are using rails framework, you should consider using compass which is layer over these frameworks (As suggested by Alan below).

Comment: I'm not really a designer, but using Blueprint has helped when I do not have templates to work with in the initial phases.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend [Blueprint](http://blueprintcss.org/) used from within [Compass](http://compass-style.org/). Compass reduces redundant CSS styles and has variables and classes. Apart from that, I have found Blueprint to be easy to use.

Answer (score 1):

What about the [twitter bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/) framework. It good for me

Comment: This certainly is comprehensive. I like that it provides a complete UI and scaffolding with modular responsive design.